# Quill editor - HTML controls on Quill text area

Tags: quill, react-quill, quil

I am trying to build a text editor for my application using react quill. My requirement is to build a sentence template and in that template, there will be some HTML controls like some free texts and some dropdown options. Is it possible to build an editor like this using Quill. Basically, instead of toolbars, I want that toolbar like options in the text editor area.

Eg:

1. Template 1 - I have **{select option}** brothers
2. Template 2 - My name is **{input box}**

In the first template, the number is a selectable item, and in the second example, the name is a free text. There are some validations on these items. that need to cover separately.

Is it possible to fulfil this requirement using Quill editor?